# Is it normal that I find a very large portion of the Triage queue to be Unsalvageable?

Tags: discussion, triage

I once read on a highly upvoted Meta answer (can't find it again though) that I should mark as "Unsalvageable" questions that require a direct input from the asker to be good, on-topic, answerable.

For example, if a question asks about debugging but lacks an essential code snippet, I flag.
If a question asks "How to" without showing research on a specific topic, I flag.
If a question asks for an external resource, I flag.
If a question asks for a broad example, I flag.

I end up flagging as Unsalvageable *a lot*. Sometimes, out of 20 reviews, more than 15 end up this way.
I do skip questions on which I am unsure (mainly questions on topics I don't know anything about).

<sub>(Out of these 15 flags 14 will end up as disputed, probably because my opinion of what a decent question is differs from the rest of the community and asking "How to do this super broad stuff" can very probably be improved by the godlike reviewers of the H&I queue.)</sub>

Since my opinion sometimes slightly differs from the other very fine reviewers of triage, such as [there](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8531877), I came to ask:
Is flagging more than 60% of the Triage queue I go through normal? Am I being too harsh?

Comment: It is a garbage pile, it *may* have an old couch that's still usable.  The more effectively the system can judge garbage, the more garbage you'll find back.  Seems it is doing a good job of it :)

Comment: Anecdotally I would agree that this sounds about right.

Comment: From my experience 50-60% of what I triage is unsalvageable.  Also see this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297085/data-on-efficacy-of-triage

Comment: Well, look at the outcome of the review you linked. Three other reviewers wanted to send it to the HIQ and one found it to be completely fine, yet the question was closed as too broad a few hours later. I'd say you were correct here and all other reviewers were wrong, which is sadly way too common in the Triage queue - there are tons of posts on meta.SO documenting that far too many people don't know what "should be improved" is about and thus overuse it on everything.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. The reason that you are voting unsalvageable a lot more than other people is because **you understand it**, and others don't, *because the language is unclear*. See [Please rename the "Should be Improved" button](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/) and [Rephrase Triage help text for “Should be improved” and “Unsalvageable”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288779/rephrase-triage-help-text-for-should-be-improved-and-unsalvageable)

Comment: Ye same thing. I decided to do some Triage again today, 11 out of 13 I rated unsalvageable, 7 flags disputed, 2 pending and 2 deemed 'helpful'.  At this point I'm actually happy with 2 'helpful' flags.

Comment: Yes there are a high percentage of unsalvageable questions and way too many reviewers don't get that. I will disagree with one of your criteria though. A question that is only bad because it lacks OP research should probably be marked Looks OK. Lack of research is more a downvote offense than a flagging offense.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty normal. Remember, we're feeding questions into this queue that the system has **good reason to think are crap:** either because of the text itself, because of flags, or because the question originates from a network that has produced a lot of lousy questions in the past.

Now, such heuristics are never 100% accurate. That's why we have folks like you asked to use your judgement on them. But... You gotta figure that a *lot* of them are gonna be.... Not so great.

Which is ok.

One thing to keep in mind though: "lousy" doesn't necessarily mean "unsalvageable". There are an awful lot of questions that aren't particularly interesting or well-written but which *could* be answered reasonably well if anyone was sufficiently bored or interested. Those can go into "Should Be Improved" - they don't need to be clogging up the close queue or moderator queue and taking focus away from *really* bad questions. Save your flags for the worst of the worst...

Answer (score 12):

The Triage text quite explicitly<sup>1</sup> tells users to mark as "Needs Improvement" content that the *author themselves* can edit to improve.

There is a strong movement on meta whose position it is that this is a waste of the Help & Improvement's queue's time, as it means every "author didn't put enough information" or "author wasn't specific enough" question has to go through "Triage", then again through "Needs Improvement" where they have to leave the top-line buttons and flag the post for closing.

In effect, the Triage and Help & Improvement queues seem to be designed to channel reviewers away from saying "this needs to be closed until the author fixes it" by guiding people away from it.

If the goal of the queues is to salvage every possible question at the expense of reviewers time, this is an appropriate design.

- "Looks Ok" -- one button, done.
- "Should be Improved" -- one button, done.
- "Skip" -- one button, done.  No magical unicorn internet points.
- "Unsalvagable" -- one button, dialog.

  - spam - often disputed by moderators.  Only extreme cases are accepted.
  - rude or abusive - probably doesn't apply much. (yay!)
  - should be closed... - you win another dialog!  Requires "unlikely to be fixed by editing" in text description.
  - a duplicate ... - reviewer now has to prove their closure by finding the duplicate.
  - in need of moderator attention - requires comment field filled in with specific and detailed information

The closure path is discouraged in descriptions **and** in the actions required.  You are more likely to get "punished" (disputed flags/etc), you have to do a multiple-step process, and you get the same magical unicorn point you'd get if you just clicked "looks ok".

Between the instruction text saying "if the author could possibly fix this question, click needs improvement" and the UI design that funnels reviewers towards "ok" and "needs improvement", anything except the most blatant junk isn't going to be "unsalvageable".

Until and unless the system is changed -- the descriptions are changed, and/or the UI flow is less biased against closing -- what you are doing may or may not be wrong, but it is mostly pointless.  You are going to lose most of your votes to close.  So the question is, do you feel like a utilitarian consequentialist, or a Kantian?

---

<sup>1</sup> Some disagree that the instructions are explicit, and think "that the author or others can edit to improve" means that a post that *only* the author could edit to improve does not qualify.

Comment: I hate H&I because of that, especially since when you *do* leave a comment for the author, you can't do anything else except click "skip".

Comment: Your question "Are you a utilitarian consequentialist or a Kantian" is very appropriate. But there is an additional question; "Is stackoverflow inclusionist or deletionist." My view is that it does not need to be either; there is no reason to delete these marginal questions where the OP needs to do more work; but it ought not to do as much to shift the burden of there being bad questions to be fixed onto the volunteers, rather than the OP. It would be best maybe if on hold questions could be permanently on hold, until the OP does something to fix them.