# User accounts that are blatant ads for escort services

Tags: discussion, accounts, rules

I was searching for an account and typed "Russian" into the search. I noticed a few results with names like "russian-escort-shanghai", "A-Russianescortmalaysia", etc...

So I then searched "escort" and a whole bunch came up that are obvious escort services with links/phone numbers in their profiles. They had no account activity (posts, comments, etc.).

Why are these accounts not banned/deleted?

Comment: Before the meta effect, some of those accounts were 2 years old with 2 or 3 views.

Comment: Also on Meta: [Inactive user accounts which appear to have only been created to advertise a product/service?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242502)

Comment: How do I know that this post isn't an indirect advertisement?

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it ironic that a pantless coder is asking about escort services?

Comment: "Why are these accounts not banned/deleted?" - probably because no-one flagged them.

Comment: Why aren't they banned?  Perhaps they are an answer to a common question that programmers face, which is the purpose of this site, isn't it?

Comment: Jeff's [statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105228) on spam in the “about me” field - *"don't hesitate to email us if you find these, and we'll fix ASAP"*

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot He is going to start an escort service, for all the right reasons.

Comment: "A whole bunch" ... well, I tried, "escort" delivers 18 entries, and 3 seem to be normal, so it is 15 ad accounts. well, they try it everywhere, but perhaps they need some advice on programming their client databases ...

Comment: um... am I the only one who wants these accounts to stay?  For uh.... research purposes.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> Why are these accounts not banned/deleted?

It's likely that the account was used to post spam, which was deleted by spam-flags. In such a case, the account itself stays there unless a moderator happens to review the incident.

User accounts [qualify for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146452/) provided that they have no visible posts, no linked accounts on other SE sites, and no visits in 6 months. This *should be* the optimal way to get rid of them: nobody has to write or read emails.

The script deleting users is subject to a throttle, which really slows the process down. [According to Shog9](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3270700#3270700),

> there are over a million users on Stack Overflow alone that qualify for deletion but haven't been deleted due to the throttle.

With dozens, if not hundreds, of spam accounts created daily on Stack Exchange, it makes sense to lean more on scripts and less on people.
So I suggest not writing to anyone about those escort services. It's up to the SE team to unclog the user deletion queue.  Hopefully, the existence of spam accounts gives  them some extra motivation to do this.

Comment: *"In such a case, the account itself stays there unless a moderator happens to review the incident"* The system auto deletes these accounts now if all it was used for was to post flagged spam. I can't say when that change was made, possibly these users pre-date that.

Comment: I never saw spam messages in SO sites. Your messing with smth.

Comment: @Joker you never saw spam on SO sites because it gets flagged and deleted within minutes.

Comment: @Joker review some posts to see spam messages.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar i track new questions and comments regulary. No spam. It is really rare. I use stackoverflow for long.

Comment: @Joker See [Reduce usefulness of posting spam to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295964) and other posts with [spam] tag here

Comment: @Joker: You are wrong. And a year isn't that "long".

Comment: Maybe the throttle should ignore accounts which only post has been deleted with spam flags.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit much more:) Yes, maybe i am too inattentive one. be prowd for your long, lol.

Comment: @Joker I am here shorter than you and I have flagged 106 spam posts. I have seen more, but quite often by the time I click to the post to mark it as spam it is already gone.

Comment: @Joker even in the review queue, they're not common; but they do exist.  In ~2500 reviews on the main SO site I've only raised 18 spam flags.  Even that overstates the numbers somewhat; IIRC more than half of the total was two individuals who were spamming their product on multiple questions as fast as search could find them something vaguely related.

Comment: I've never seen deer so therefore there are no such things as deer.

Comment: @Joker [Hundreds of posts are flagged as spam every day, and even more of them are blocked before even being posted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286615/1157054)

Comment: @Qix  I just flagged a Yeti

Comment: I think running a script is a great solution. What do they mean by "throttle?" I have never heard of this term in programming before

Comment: @onebree [Throttling process (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throttling_process_(computing)). The script is limited to deleting 1000 users per week. It probably shouldn't be...

Comment: Thank you. I think that count should be based on a percentage of accounts at that given moment. OR A one-time edit to the script to just delete all eligible accounts.