# How long my account will active in stack overflow without login?

Tags: discussion

It may happen I will be incapable to login into stack overflow for long time. So my question is, how long my account will active in stack overflow without login?

Comment: forever....or at least until the world ends in 2012.

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted

Comment: and - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298592/3041194